Does Mono (6.x) support AspNetSynchronizationContext?
I have an ASP.NET project on .NET 4.5 and I can't seem to get async-await controller actions to work with HttpContext.Current. I've tried everything, such as setting httpRuntime targetFramework to 4.5, using aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext = true but when I step through a call HttpContext.Current is null after any async-await calls (I've made sure to NOT have the async code resume on another thread) and SynchronizationContext.Current is always null, before and after any async-await calls.
So I have to assume that perhaps mono doesn't have support for ASP.NET re: async-await. I'm running via xsp4 on macos with mono 6.12.0.
UPDATE: I just tried the same project under full .NET on a Windows machine and SynchronizationContext.Current was set to an instance of AspNetSynchronizationContext.

You might now report to the new maintainers and see if they would like to help, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mono/info And migrating to .NET 8 is another way.

I don't have time to migrate right now - looks like running on regular .NET works so I'll abandon using mono for these projects as they are heavy into using async-await and (for some reason) storing stuff in HttpContext.Items.
